# Questions on structuring a flutter(-bloc) app

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Say I have an App that uses Blocs/Cubits and I have a few repositories, like a AuthRepository and a FriendsRepository.

Now the problem is the following: I want the repositories to be in different packages than the actual app, like such:

```
|-app
  |-lib
    |...
  |-pubspec.yaml
|-auth_repository
  |-lib
    |...
  |-pubspec.yaml
|-friends_repository
  |-lib
    |...
  |-pubspec.yaml
```

How would I share the models?

Am I not allowed to use the models inside the repositories/do I have to have special models that are converted by the blocs/cubits to ones in the app?

Or do I make another package with the shared models?

Or should I just make a folder in lib to house the repositories and then just share the models in the lib/models folder?

Comment: You can do the 3rd option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create your own flutter package click [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-create-publish-and-manage-flutter-packages-b4f2cd2c6b90).
And also if you want, you can get inspiration from the example [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial), it's an example of a firebase login application with an AuthenticationRepository in different packages, as you're looking for.
**Just look at its structure it can help you.**